# WIndows.Open brokes scripts until new tab is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a simple bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
...
 <span data-action>Click me!</span>
...
</div>
```

And the following code:

```
$("#someButtonThatOpensModal").click(function() {
   $("#myModal").modal("show");
});

$("[data-action]").click(function() {
    window.open("http://some resource");
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
});
```

The problem is that after clicking button inside modal, that modal dodesn't appear again until tab opened from code via `window.open` is closed. That happens **only in Chrome**. Moreover, I am not able to refresh page until child-tab is closed.

What can I do? I want to "fire and forget" new tab - why it has influence of JS code?

EDIT:
It seems that printing breaks original tab. Newly opened tab calls `window.print()` on load, and original tab is broken until you close or cancel printing. On ther borwser, you cannot switch tab until you cancel or confirm printing. How can I can solve it in chrome?

Comment: `#("[data-action]")` is that a typo or actual code?

Comment: Just typo, corrected ;)